# select first, second . . . div in a jquery while loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im making a quiz module where i want to let the administrator add more possibilities to the questions and furthermore delete individual ones. 
I made the following jquery, and if i dont delete any of the items, it will append the right numbers to the id in each of the rows. however if i start deleting, it will mix the id's around.
It is important that i get this right, as it is supposed to go in a database, from which users can pull it out, and show it in the same order as it was created.

Therefore i made a while loop, to check if the numbers behind the id's are in the correct order (if not, it should replace the id with the correct number in the end of it) as i increments after a row is deleted. I just cant seem to get it working!

jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/g8ysemf0/

jQuery

```
            $("#btnid").click(function () {
            $('.valgmulighed:last').clone().attr('id', 'valgmulighed' + ($('.valgmulighed').length + 1)).insertAfter('.valgmulighed:last');
        });

        var max = $('.valgmulighed').length;
        var i = 1;

        $('body').on('click', '.slet', function () {

            if ($('.slet').length > 1)
                $(this).closest('.valgmulighed').remove();

            while (i < max) {
                if ($('.valgmulighed').length != '.valgmulighed' + i) {
                    $('.valgmulighed').attr('id', 'valgmulighed' + i);
                }
                i++;
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="toptekst">
  <span>Tilføj valgmuligheder her</span>
  <input type="button" id="btnid" value="+" />
</div>
<div class="valgmulighed" id="valgmulighed1">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="sv1" /><span class="label-text">Rigtigt</span>
  </label>
  <input id="Text3" type="text" class="spmtekst2" placeholder="Tekst valgmulighed" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Tekst valgmulighed'" />
  <div class="slet">
    <span>Slet</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of checking IDs for the correct order after questions have been shifted around, why not loop through each question before they are submitted and increment a counter that just applies the correct ID regardless?

Comment: but how would you go around that? i'm almost sure that my while loop is garbage anyway, as i'm not really that good of a coder.
how would such a solution look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is easy to delete an item and give new ids to remaining items:

```
$(".slet").on("click", function(event) {
    // remove the item
    $(this).closest('.valgmulighed').remove();
    // set id of remaining items
    $(".valgmulighed").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("id", "valgmulighed" + index);
    });
});
```

But you might not need to set new `id`s every time you delete a question.  Is it acceptable to populate your database with a sparse set of `id`s?  e.g.,

```
<div id="valgmulighed1">...</div>
<div id="valgmulighed3">...</div>
<div id="valgmulighed4">...</div>
<div id="valgmulighed9">...</div>
```

?  If this is ok, then simply increment your `<div>` id upon creation and do nothing upon deletion.

Comment: you got it! But why wouldn't it be okay? i will just make it as a string in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

To fully flesh out what I suggested, see this updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g8ysemf0/2/

First, there was no functionality to remove quiz items, so I put the entire set in a wrapper to be able to set an event that detects clicks on dynamically generated `.slet` objects

```
$('#wrapper').on('click','div.slet', function(){$(this).parent().remove();})
```

Next, I put in a button that would be used to submit the page to the database. I set a function on that button that will loop through each item that exists after the user is done editing, then assign new IDs to the items:

```
 $('#submit-quiz').click(function(){
   //create counter
   var counter = 0;
   //go through each item and assign them new IDs
   $('div.valgmulighed').each(function(){
     //add to the counter for each quiz item
     counter++;
     //set the ID
     $(this).attr('id', 'valgmulighed' + counter);
   });
//Any submit functions/logic after all IDs are assigned
return true;
});
```

The "accepted" answer is a good approach too, with the IDs being updated as items are deleted. It's all a matter of when you want to perform that action.